# Select data from two table row (tr)

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, textarea, tr

I want when `Add` is clicked [3rd `td` of `tr`], Javascript/JQuery will select this `id` AND the `val()` from textarea that positioned immediately after that id [not all the textarea].....

HTML

```
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>                  
                    <td>£ 10</td>
                    <td><b id='1' class='btn'>Add</b></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class='form-group'>
                        <label>Add Note:</label>
                        <textarea class='form-control'></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

               <tr>
                    <td>B</td>                  
                    <td>£ 10</td>
                    <td><b id='2' class='btn'>Add</b></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class='form-group'>
                        <label>Add Note:</label>
                        <textarea class='form-control'></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>C</td>                  
                    <td>£ 10</td>
                    <td><b id='3' class='btn'>Add</b></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div class='form-group'>
                        <label>Add Note:</label>
                        <textarea class='form-control'></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

JS

```
    <script>

        $('b.btn').click(function(){

        var x_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var note = $('textarea').val();

        }); 

    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe you can add an `id` attribute to each textarea ?

Comment: There are lots of textarea ... and these add button and textarea will be generated via PHP.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `note` to:

```
var note = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('textarea').val();
```

Comment: .......@j08691, This is awesome ..... 100% working .... thanks a lot for the quick solution...

Comment: @TariqulIslam You're welcome. If you feel that this answer helped, or answered, your question, please feel free to upvote and/or accept it.